# averaging a large vector after elementwise value assignment in a loop

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, data-science, bigdata

I want to speed up this code:

```
a=np.linspace(0, 10, 2**20)
b=np.random.rand(a.shape[0])
res=np.zeros_like(a)
func = lambda x, y: np.exp((x-y)**2)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    res=res+func(a, b[i])
res=res/a.shape[0]
```

### this code will take a lot of time to execute, I also can use np.mean() after i calculated the matrix of func(X, Y) but it requires a lot of memory which i do not have.
Do anyone know how to deal with this problem? or how to have a trade off between the two methods?

Comment: What is x in ```res=res+func(x, b[i])```? I tested this with x = a and np.mean(np.exp((a-b)**2)) instead of your loop gave me an immediate result. Is this a memory problem for you?

Comment: @Flow thank you, i corrected it. 
it takes years to finish. I want it to get finished faster.